# HashLists in Perl

Tags: perl, list, hash, replace

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $string = $ARGV[0];

my @caracteresSeparados = split(//,$string);

my $temp;
my @complementoADN;

foreach my $i(@caracteresSeparados){

    if($i eq 'a'){
        $temp = 't';
        push(@complementoADN,$temp);
    }elsif($i eq 'c'){
       $temp = 'g';
       push(@complementoADN,$temp);
    }elsif($i eq 'g'){
       $temp = 'c';
       push(@complementoADN,$temp);
    }elsif($i eq 't'){
       $temp = 'a';
       push(@complementoADN,$temp);
    }
}

printf("@complementoADN\n");
```

I've this code that receive by argument one string with A,C,G,T letters.

My objective with this script is to receive that string that the user just can write these letters above and then should print in console the same letters replaced, i mean

- A replace by T
- C replace by G
- G replace by C
- T replace by A

I'm not restricting user to introduce other letters, but it's no problem for now...

One Example:

user introduce argument: ACAACAATGT

Program should print: TGTTGTTACA

My script is doing it right.

My question is, can i do it with Hash Lists? If yes can you show me that script with Hashes working? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Firstly, be careful with your terminology: "hash" and "list" are both types in Perl, "hash list" is not; I presume you just mean "hash". Secondly, it's not very clear what you mean by "do it with hashes" - are you looking for a way to simplify your function, or make it more flexible? Why and how do you think hashes will help, and where are you stuck implementing this yourself?

Comment: `perl -pe'tr/ACGT/TGCA/'` is the short version of the program you want.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't involve hashes, but if you're looking to simplify your program, look up [the `tr//` ("transliteration") operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr). I believe the below will be identical to yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $string = $ARGV[0];

my $complementoADN = $string;
$complementoADN =~ tr/ACGT/TGCA/;

print $complementoADN, "\n";
```

Comment: But its not do replace all string "ACGT" into "TGCA". It's each letter .. I thought we could do it with Hashes like:

Key -> Value

A -> T

C -> G

G -> C

T -> A

Comment: @AndréBarradas The [`tr//` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) performs "transliteration" - it replaces each character in its first argument with the corresponding character in its second argument. See [this live demonstration](http://codepad.org/XCD3vMlW) with the input hard-coded to the example in your question.

Answer (score 2):

IMSoP's answer is correct - in this case, `tr` is the most appropriate tool for the job.

However, yes, it can also be done with a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $original = 'ACAACAATGT';
my $replaced;

my %flip = (
  A => 'T',
  C => 'G',
  G => 'C',
  T => 'A',
);

for (split '', $original) {
  $replaced .= $flip{$_};
} 

say $replaced;
```

Output:

```
TGTTGTTACA
```